# Get data from GET request in node.js parameters undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, get

I am trying to get parameters from get request in Node.js through Angular.JS but getting undefined in output

> http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard?id=582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238

My CRUD is

```
"dashboard":{
     schema:DashboardSchema,
     custom:[{
         type:"after",
         request: "get",
         controller: dashboardController.dashboard
     }]
}
```

My Node.js code is

```
dashboard: function(req,res){
     console.log("here");
     console.log(req.params);
     console.log(req.params.id);
     return res.status(200).send({"data":"123"});
});
```

The console window shows like this

> GET /admin/dashboard?id=582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238 200 153.463 ms - 14
>   In decode data  { id: '582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238' }
>   here 
>   { id: undefined }
>   undefined

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard?id=582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238**

Here as you are passing in query so try
**req.query.id**

If you are passing the parameters as
**http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/582c5211c8a8e06c0849a238**
then you can use req.params.id

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked Answer would be accepted after 10 minutes according to stackoverflow