# Express Router GET request console.log shows undefined request parameters

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I've looked on SO for an identical questions, since I feel this is a pretty simple error on my part, but the closest thing I've found is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300727/get-data-from-get-request-in-node-js-parameters-undefined). I'm learning Node.JS, and am writing a relatively simple endpoint to receive get requests for a certain artist:

```
router.get("/:artistID", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(req.params.artistId);
  res.send(req.params);
})
```

What I expect to see is **1)**, a JSON object with { artistID: "whatIsent"}, **2)** a "whatIsent", and then **3)** the same JSON object as a response when I use an API testing utility such as Postman.

Results 1) and 3) occur as expected, but here's what I see in my console:

```
{ artistID: 'whatIsent' }
undefined
```

Here is the GET request I send:
http://localhost:8080/artists/whatIsent.

What exactly is going on? Is Express translating `artistId` into some intermediate object that is not a string?

Edit: I used `typeof req.params.artistId`, and it also returns undefined...

Comment: `artistId !== artistID`

Comment: Oh dear... now I feel like an idiot. You want to just answer the question and I'll accept it so we can close this and forget it ever happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

It should be `artistID` instead of `artistId`.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the variable as `artistID` and trying to get `artistId`. Parameters are case sensitive.